# Integration and Unit tests

Tags: testing, jestjs, tdd, integration

In the last days I studied about tests with Jest, but i don't understood the next.
When I have integration tests I don't use mock? Mock are used just on unit tests?

**UPDATE**
Today, in my company, the approach that we follow is: Unit tests always mock all external access data, and integration tests should not mock.

Is interesting, associate integration tests with hlg environment, because you can discovery easily what and where broke software

Comment: There's no solid answer, because there aren't universal definitions of what unit and integration tests are. Typically I've used unit tests to refer to tests of isolated parts of the system, implying more [test doubles](https://engineering.pivotal.io/post/the-test-double-rule-of-thumb/) like mocks, and integration tests to refer to tests of multiple parts of the system brought together, implying fewer test doubles, but you can write integration tests where some parts are still replaced with test doubles and unit tests that don't involve any.

Comment: You may need mocks if there are other units involved besides the ones you integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Mocks are a kind of [Test Double](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html) - a test-specific replacement of a dependency, for purposes of making automated tests deterministic.

There's no universally accepted formal definition of what constitutes a *unit test*, but in this context, I find the following definition (essentially my own wording) useful:

*A unit test is an automated test that tests a unit in isolation of its dependencies.*

This definition, however, conveniently avoids defining what *a unit* is, but that's less important in this context.

Likewise, we can define an integration test as an automated test that exercises the System Under Test (SUT) with its real dependencies. Thus, instead of replacing the database dependency with a Test Double, the test exercises the SUT integrated with a real database, and so on.

Thus, with this view of integration testing, no Test Doubles are required because all real dependencies are integrated.

There's another view of integration testing that considers integration testing the exercise of various software components (*units*, if you will) with each other, while still replacing out-of-process resources like databases or web services with Test Doubles. This is often easier to accomplish, and can be a valuable technique, but whether you decide to call these *unit tests* or *integration tests* is largely a question of personal preference.

Unfortunately, there's no universally accepted consistent definition of these terms. I usually try to stick with the vocabulary documented in [xUnit Test Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com), which is the most comprehensive and internally consistent body of work on the topic (that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

From ISTQB definition, Integration is “A test level that focuses on interactions between components or systems.”
So you can have integration test between units, or between different components, or between subsystems. You may also integrate system of systems.

You can read [unit test in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

So you can use unit test framework (mock/stub) to do integration test also, but when integration test of whole application usually requires a full environment setup, which unit test framework can not do.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents:

- Unit tests - always use mock. The "unit" of test is a method.
- Integration tests - never use mock. The "unit" of test is a class.
- End-to-end tests - uses the actual program. The "unit" of test is a single "happy path".